# isinstance not working when list is used to check in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, isinstance

I am trying to load a text file that has two column data, separated by a tab. The first column values could be either integers or floats, while the second column will always be floats. Now, I am using `isinstance` to see if my first column is integer or float. However, `isinstance` doesn't seem to work when a list of values or the final element of the list is used. This is my code:

```
time_t = []
with open(logF, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data_t = line.split()
        time_t.append(data_t[0])

time_length_max = time_t[-1]
print time_length_max

if isinstance(time_length_max, (int, long)):
   print "True"
 else:
   print "False"
```

The output I get is:

```
10000
False
```

Suppose, I declare `time_length_max = 10000`, instead of `time_length_max = time_t[-1]`, I get:

```
10000
True
```

Comment: This looks like more of a conversion issue at the time of reading the file, generally it retrieves the value in the form of strings. So that is likely the case here

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as suggested in

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/379966/350429

```
def num(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return float(s)

time_t = []
with open(logF, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data_t = line.split()
        time_t.append(num(data_t[0]))

time_length_max = time_t[-1]
print time_length_max

if isinstance(time_length_max, (int, long)):
   print "True"
 else:
   print "False"
```

Beware that the value should be a number in the file, if it is an empty string then it will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks @adifire. Your approach works fine. However, it fails when I check the entire list. For example, instead of `time_length_max` in `if isinstance(time_length_max, (int, long))`, If I use `if isinstance(time_t (int, long))`, it prints `False` indicating floats. However, my time_t is a list of 1 to 10000, all of which are integers.

Comment: Well actually isinstance(time_t, (int,long)) will return false because it is a list, not because it is a float or anything. To check for the whole list, you would have to check the type of individual values in time_t.

Answer (score 0):

`split` returns strings.  You probably want to cast your string to an integer before asking if it is an instance of an integer.

```
>>> type('10000')
<type 'str'>
>>> type(10000)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(int('10000'))
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnMee. While, `int('10000')` works if the value is integer, but fails when its float. I did this: `time_t.append(int(data_t[0]))`. This worked fine for the case when `time_t` was an integer, but failed for a float value.